# What is the fastest way through the early phases?

Tags: stack-egg

How would I get past the private beta and public beta phases faster?

Is it based on 'surviving' for a number of days?

Is it based on getting several stats at a certain level of stars, or does it weigh certain stats more heavily than others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the minimum time for private beta is provably 17 days. The progress seemed only related to the number of hearts you have. And you can't get two hearts at the same time during private beta (But I think it happened at least once after graduation, while traffic is full and answer is not). By alternating ask/answer, you always get one in each turn and it never decreases.

Not sure about public beta. Graduation in 99 days is possible (using [bot](http://pastebin.com/N5A74eEM), without flags, but it has a bug so 1 day is wasted in private beta, so it is 100 days actually). But I don't know how optimal it is.